# JavaScript box game - inner div exceeds outer div boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance, javascript-objects

[Box Game on my github](https://aanchalch.github.io/BoxGame/)

I can't get the inner div to stay within the boundaries of the outer div properly in the mobile view. Please help me out by checking what's wrong with this code. I'm new to javascript.

HTML

```
                <div class="GameArea">
                    <div class="message">
                        <h4>How to Play</h4>
                        <div>
                            Just click on the blue box to score points!
                        </div>
                        X:<span class="x">0</span>
                        Y:<span class="y">0</span>
                        <br>
                        Score <span class="score">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="output">
                        <div><h4 class="text-center banner">Let's start!</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS

```
function move() {
    let speed = Math.random() * 10;
    const box = document.querySelector(".box");
    let bounds = output.getBoundingClientRect();
    box.steps--;
    if (box.steps < 0) {
        box.direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        box.steps = Math.random() * 20;
    }
    if (box.direction == 0 && box.x < bounds.right - 440) {
        box.x += speed;
    }
    if (box.direction == 1 && box.x > bounds.left) {
        box.x -= speed;
    }
    if (box.direction == 2 && box.y < bounds.bottom - 165) {
        box.y += speed;
    }
    if (box.direction == 3 && box.y > bounds.top) {
        box.y -= speed;
    }
    box.style.top = box.y + "px";
    box.style.left = box.x + "px";
    window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet so we can help you

Comment: The issue is that your green box is set to 70% height and width so that is variable.  You need to get the x,y, of the green box and make sure the x of the box does not cross the x of the green box minus the width of the blue box so box.x > (geenbox.x + greenbox.width - box width)  for right and  for the y  box.y <  greenbox.y + greenbox.height - box.height) for bottom. then do greenbox.x and greenbox.y for the left and top   This is because the x,y is the top left corner of the box so you have to take into account the width.height of the box and where on the screen the greenbox actually starts